# iOS UITextField formatted for time

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I have a UITextField which I created programmatically. This text field is used to input a time. The placeholder text is "00:00:00.000". When the text field is tapped, a number pad will appear. Ideally, I want the gray place holder text to remain as the user types. As they enter a number, it replaces the gray zeros in the place holder text and skips over the colons and period (leaving the format intact without the user entering any punctuation). If it is not possible to keep the place holder text and replace it as the user types, I would like the punctuation to automatically be entered.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason to use a text field over a date picker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS has a [UIDatePicker](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html) control for this, if you want to go the way you are going then you will have handle all the user input your self.

Comment: Duh! I wasn't thinking about a UIDatePicker because I have my text field in a table view. I am going to try and look into showing the picker instead of the keyboard.